# How to render daz character hair in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I am trying to render Daz character hair in cycles but its looks weird and no color,Daz hair textures is different.its not looks my regular hair texture.here is the textures.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer from a guy name javiermichael here is the nodes setting!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Node setting is the Key to all.

For some reasons materials with some transparency, such as hair or eye cornea etc...

For each part of the hair (or other material with transparency) You need to connect **Image texture** node color output to **Mix color alpha** node color 1 input

[image: DAZ-to_blender hair Fix] (see image)

Please, be careful. Materials in DAZ export rather complex, and You should find exactly that part, which is responsible for transparency. It consists of **mapping** node, **image texture** node and **mix color/alpha** node, and all this is plugged as factor to **Shadier mix Alpha** node.

Hope this will help.